# What should UN resolution demand?

Tags: cold-war, nuclear-war

Two small countries run by tin-pot dictators that nobody likes are fighting each other,sort of like the Iran-Iraq war, and nobody cares very much about them. That is until one of the dictators acquires nukes  and wipes the other country from the map, and takes over their territory.

The security council, including both super powers USA & USSR, are not pleased to say the least. They put the remaining dictator on embargo, and put navy force to enforce it. However they fear that the remaining  dictator has a nuke or two left so they don't want to risk military action. They fear that if they press him too hard he might use them on some of the other neighbors, there are several large cities in his SCUD range.

UN adopts a resolution that demands remaining dictator to step down and face  the tribunal for crimes against humanity, together with his flunkies.

What should UN demand to be done about land of the conquered dictator?

Comment: Are you aware that nukes are not sold at flea markets nor can be made in the backyard where nobody sees them?

Comment: @L.Dutch I know, but that is the premise of my story.

Comment: Where are the countries located? How do they get their incomes (mines and oil, trade, services)?

Comment: @AlexP There's agreement among the security council that he should be removed, and volunteers to do the actual fighting . The problem is that risking few millions  deaths is last option. They want to make the regime collapse through embargo & clandestine support of the opposition.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to answers questions about your world, rather than the story you're looking to tell within a world. This appears to be a question about the latter. As the United Nations is a real-world organization, I would suggest looking at their charter to see what they can and cannot do. That should at least solve the dispute going on in comments...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56532/discussion-on-question-by-naamnaamsaddam-what-should-un-resolution-demand).

Answer (score 5):

## They have forfeited their sovereignty as a nation

[There are four different reasons for which a country may lose its sovereignty](https://youtu.be/cp4U3garYSs?t=10m48s):

- Violations of [The Genocide Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genocide_Convention)
- Violations of [The Non-Proliferation Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_on_the_Non-Proliferation_of_Nuclear_Weapons)
- Giving aid, comfort and harbour to wanted terrorists
- Threatening another country's sovereignty

This tin-pot country of yours just nuked three of four points. They have blatantly forfeited their sovereignty and are now subject to having their leadership removed by the international community. The leadership will face charges for crimes against humanity. Also the country will need to pay reparations to the other tin-pot country for the destruction and the clean-up of the mess they left behind.

A UN resolution would demand, in the very least:

- That the leadership of the nation immediately orders the cessation of hostilities
- That the leadership of the nation then surrenders all executive power
- That all persons responsible for the attack make themselves available for prosecuction at the [ICC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Criminal_Court)
- That all weapons of mass destruction be made available for inspection, confiscation and dismantlement
- That reparations be paid to the attacked country

The fact that they may still have nukes is a troublesome matter. So how to then go about it if the leadership in question gives the UN the finger is another thing. But the resolution would seek the things above.

Comment: I've removed the side notes as they are likely to cause off-topic arguments rather than add to the answer.